# (Py)Spark: df.sample(0.1) doesn't affect runtime of df.toPandas()

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

I'm working on a data set of ~ 100k lines in PySpark, and I wan't to convert it to Pandas. The data on web clicks contains string variables and is read from a .snappy.orc file in an Amazon S3 bucket via `spark.read.orc(...)`.

The conversion is running too slow for my application (for reasons very well explained here on stackoverflow), and thus I've tried to downsample my spark DataFrame to one tenth - the dataset is so large, that the statistical analysis I need to do is probably still valid. I however need to repeat the analysis for 5000 similar datasets, why speed the a concern.

What surprised me, is that the running time of: `df.sample(false, 0.1).toPandas()` is exactly the same as `df.toPandas()` (approx 180s), and so I don't get the reduction in running time I was hoping for.

I'm suspecting it may be a question of putting in a `.cache()` or `.collect()`, but I can't figure out a proper way to fit it in.

Comment: 100K lines doesn't struct me as particularly large. At the same time `sample` requires a full scan of the data which might expect comparable execution time. Please [edit] your question and describe (optimally with corresponding code) how `df` is obtained. Also, if that's not obvious from the code, how many columns do you have and what is the approximate size of the raw data.

Comment: Thanks! I've added more comments describing the problem.

Comment: have you tried to do .persist() on the pyspark df?

Comment: And could you measure execution time of `df.foreach(lambda x: None)` or `df._jdf.queryExecution().toRdd().count()`?